# Spying on an object after cast using Mockito

Tags: java, object, casting, mockito, spy

I'm using Mockito to write some unit tests. I ran into the following scenario:

```
public interface A extends ABase { }
```

where `ABase` is an interface with concrete methods in it. I'm using `Mockito.spy()` on an instance of A, and I want to verify a method `foo()` declared in `ABase` is called in a piece of code I'm writing. Inside said code, `A` is cast to `ABase` and `foo()` is called. However, I get a build error (method not found) on the line where I try and verify `foo()` was called in my test method, like this:

```
A bar = spy(new A());
//... (function I'm testing is called, A is cast to ABase and foo() called)
verify(bar, times(1)).foo(); //problem line, foo not found
```

Any suggestions as to what to do? Thanks!

EDIT: there were some errors in my original question. My apologies, it should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that `ABase` cannot be a class, because `A` is an interface and interfaces cannot extend classes:

You're passing `A` to `verify`. This shouldn't even compile. Try using `bar` instead. Mockito expects a mock or spy to be passed to `verify` so you can verify invocations on a particular argument.

Comment: My bad, I missed the interface keyword when looking at the code. I was also pretty confused looking at it. Also, `A` was a typo, you are correct. It still doesn't compile given these two things however.

Comment: @VaishakLalsangi, could you provide more of your source code? I just checked it on some of my source and it worked as expected.